# При запуске ОС на Cosmos пишет "PS/2 controller is not supported."

Tags: c#, .net

При запуске ОС на Cosmos пишет "PS/2 controller is not supported". Как это убрать? При запуске в Virtual Box все работает отлично

Comment: Какой процесор?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67514455/12888024

Comment: @aepot AMD Ryzen 5, в прикрепленном ответе ничего не помогло, версия космоса стоит последняя, загружался с диска и с флешки

Comment: Я уже не помню, где именно, но когда искал, видел баг, связанный с проблемами именно на AMD. Но раз версия последняя, тогда скорее всего это не ваш случай.